# How do you get all the functions defined in the namespace in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I want to see all the functions defined in the current namespace. Is there a function I can call in the REPL that can answer this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`ns-map`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-map) function along with the [`*ns*`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/%2ans%2a) variable.

```
(ns-map *ns*)
```

All the namespace functions are outlined on the [clojure.org namespaces](http://clojure.org/namespaces) page.

Comment: So the complete form for the OP's question is `(ns-map *ns*)`.